# React native http fetch request not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, react-native, fetch

I'm new to react native trying to do the http request using fetch method (also tried axios). I'm using PHP as backend. What I'm trying is to print the JSON object returned from server in react native.

I'm sure that the response is returning from server cause I printed the result and it is a JSON array. But when I consoled the `responseData` using Chrome dev tools I got this `[]`. I don't know where the mistake is.

**index.js**

```
    componentDidMount(){

        fetch('http://xxxxxxxxxx/result.php', {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(response =>response.json())
          .then((responseData) =>
          {
              console.log(responseData);
              this.setState({
                  user: (responseData.name),
                  loaded:true,
              })

        });         
}
    render(){
        return(
        <Card>  
  <CardTitle style={styles.containerStyle} title={this.state.user} />
</Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Also my php is script is as follows

**result.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$check_json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj1= json_decode($check_json);
$uid =$obj1->{'uuid'};
$blood = $obj1->{'bloodgroup'};
$loc = $obj1->{'place'};
$prep =$mysqli->prepare("select token,name,uuid from signup where location 
like '".$loc."%' and bloodgroup= ?");
$prep->bind_param("s",$blood);
$prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result();
$payload= array();
while($row= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $payload[]= array('name' =>$row['name']
                    'uuid' =>$row['name']);
}
$obj2 =json_encode($payload);
echo $obj2;
?>
```

and the response from server is

```
 [{"name":"angel","uuid":"b4b8a266-60cf-4e30-a778-596316d1a4a2"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using axios. You can check the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) After you have done `npm install axios` and imported axios into your component you can try:

```
componentDidMount(){
axios
  .get('https://www.your-url.com/path-to-your-php-api')
  .then(({ data })=> {
    this.setState({ 
      user: data.name
    });
  })
  .catch((err)=> {})
}
```

if you still have problems, post the url that returns JSON so I can take a look.

Check your PHP API, if the object is returning empty, make sure to encode json. Here is an example you can try

```
$myObj->name = "Michel Arteta";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer will try this.

Comment: Still same error getting `[]`. json response is `[{"name":"angel","uuid":"b4b8a266-60cf-4e30-a778-596316d1a4a2"}]`.I'm writing the response to a text file.I can't see this response by taking the `url` which i mentioned inside `fetch`.

Comment: What's your url that prints the json. Do you have it on a server?

Comment: Yes ,so i've printed the json object `echo $obj2` but `[]` this is coming.But when i printed `hii`.it is coming .So problem is with  server side i think is it??

Comment: yes, check your PHP api, I have added a code to test. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Yeah i've tried that example.Problem is with php code.Thank you so much for finding this out.I'll double check my code.

Comment: `$myObj->name = $row['name'];
$myObj->age = $row['uuid'];` can i give like this inside `while loop`?

Comment: Yes, I will use a foreach, like this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 1):

Is your url is `http` ? Do you try on IOS ?

(if yes, you need add your domain to white list in XCode )

By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more secure to add exceptions just for those domains;

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this.Problem was with the react part.I was trying to fetch this response returned in a different page.Actually the response returned from server was correct.